# How to modify selector? Flutter Webscraper getElement()

Tags: flutter, web-scraping, css-selectors, web-crawler, selector

I'm using flutter webscraper package(import 'package:web_scraper/web_scraper.dart')
to crawl some stuff's titles.
But when I use selector(get selector using developer's tool -> right click -> copy selector) or modified selector,
getElement() function can't read the titles.

I thought the cause is a wrong selector.
But another site's 'modified' selector works well, no originial selector.

I don't know how to modify selector well.
Please  help me.
the Below is my code.

`webScraper = WebScraper(beongaeUrl);
print(webScraper);
if (await webScraper
.loadWebPage('/search/products?q=apple')) {
c_productNames = webScraper.getElement(
'#root > div > div > div.sc-iNovjJ.cOuQhS > div > div.sc-gcJTYu.ikNLYu > div > div > a > div.sc-kNBZmU.kmMbIN > div.sc-eopZyb.jKZagR' , ['title']);
print(c_productNames.length);

}`
and the result is
I/flutter (15776): https://m.bunjang.co.kr
I/flutter (15776): Instance of 'WebScraper'
I/flutter (15776): 0